# Digits of irrational numbers, organized chaos, modular arithmetic, and uniform equilibrium distribution

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, stochastic-processes, dynamical-systems, irrational-numbers

Is there a simple increasing sequence $\{ x_n \}$ of positive integers such that $x_n \mbox{ mod } b$ is the $n$-th digit of some known mathematical irrational constant in some integer base $b$? Perhaps a sequence simple enough that it is possible to prove that the digits in question are evenly distributed?

Of course the sequence $\lfloor b^n\pi \rfloor$ fits the bill for the number $\pi$ but it is intractable. A sequence such as $y_n = \lfloor b^n\pi \rfloor -b \phi_n$ where $\phi_n$ is an integer, such that $\{ y_n \}$ is smooth enough, for instance a very smoothly growing sequence of perfect squares?

I have spent years trying to solve this mystery using dynamical systems, ergodic stochastic processes and their equilibrium distributions (see [here](https://www.datasciencecentral.com/profiles/blogs/fee-book-applied-stochastic-processes)) but to no avail so far. I have made great progress no doubt, but I feel like I am traveling through space trying to reach the closest star besides the sun, and I am just barely outside the solar system.

Comment: The digits of every non-construceted irrational number ($\pi,e,\sqrt{2}$ and so on) have no known pattern, so I strongly doubt that we ever will have a "formula" directly calculating the $n$-th digit. Only for $\pi$ and base $2$ , such a "formula" is known, but the calculation also is not "direct" , but at least we can determine it "efficiently".

Comment: Whether an irrational number is normal (or at least contains every finite digit-string) will probably be undecidable forever.

Comment: I might be up to something with $e, \pi^2$ and $\log 2$. For $\log 2$, based on the fact that its $k$-th digit in base $b$ is $\lim_{n \rightarrow\infty} \lfloor b^k(\frac{1}{n+1} + \cdots \frac{1}{n+n})\rfloor$ modulo $b$. Similar argument for $\log 3$.